# Limit number of decimals on input Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an input field and I want to limit the number of decimals that a user should type.
Ex:(10.123), if he type more, no change will be made, the value will stay stuck. Right now the user gets an error, but is not enough.
PS. I am using Vue-Bootstrap.
I try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/288/) but limits the whole number not just decimals.

```
<b-form-input
    type="number"
    id="contract-input"
    v-model="contract"
></b-form-input>
```

On view it works fine.

```
<p>{{parseFloat(contract).toFixed(2)}}</p>
```

Comment: I attach the link in description for jsfiddle and I tried max-length, but of course it doesn't what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call a method that would restrict the decimals in your variable on `@input` event.
Example:

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {contract : ''},
        methods: {
          restrictDecimal () {
            this.contract=this.contract.match(/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}/);
          }
        }
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <h3>Restrict decimals in number</h3>
  <div>
    <input type='number' v-model='contract' @input="restrictDecimal">
    
    <b>{{contract}}</b>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.contract is not a function".   BUT, the result is what I needed!  Thank you!!